# If data present, replace with data from another column based on row ID

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, replace

I would like to replace data in columns rep1 to rep4. The data in these columns match unique ID's in the first column. I want to replace the data in columns rep1-rep4 with data in the value column with the corresponding ID row. So, for the second row "b", I want to replace "a" in the column "rep1" with the corresponding value in row "a", in this case, -400.

```
ID  rep1  rep2  rep3  rep4  value
a                           -400
b   a                       -300
c   a     b                 -200
d   a     b     c           -300
e   a     b     c     d     -400
f                           -400
g   f                       -400
h                           -400
i                           -200
j   k     l                 -300
k   l                       -200
l                           -300
m                           -300
```

It seems like using `ifelse(!is.na())` might be able to do something here, but I'm not sure how to match the ID data in columns rep1 to rep4 to the corresponding row in the ID column, identifying what data in "value" is supposed to be used in the replacement. Can this be done in the same dataframe, or does it need to be split into two different dataframes to work?

Here is the data using `dput()`

```
structure(list(ID = structure(1:13, .Label = c("a", "b", "c", 
"d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m"), class = "factor"), 
    rep1 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
    5L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "a", "f", "k", "l"), class = "factor"), 
    rep2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "b", "l"), class = "factor"), 
    rep3 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "c"), class = "factor"), rep4 = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
    "d"), class = "factor"), value = c(-400L, -300L, -200L, -300L, 
    -400L, -400L, -400L, -400L, -200L, -300L, -200L, -300L, -300L
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -13L))
```

Comment: Can you post your sample data in `dput` format? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (`df` is the name of your dataset.)

Comment: @RuiBarradas I added the sample data using `dput` to the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a variant with tidyverse:

```
df %>% mutate_at(vars(rep1:rep4), ~ value[match(., ID)])
```

Explanation:

- `mutate_at`  allows to select a range of variables to be modified
- the `~ ... .` (quosure style lambda notation) allows to use an expression in which `.` (dot) stands for the column to be modified. Otherwise you would have to use `function(x) df$value[match(x, df$ID)]`, which is a lot to type.
- `vars()` are necessary in `mutate_at` to be able to select columns without quotes (otherwise you would need to use `2:5` or `paste0("rep", 1:4)`).

Comment: This worked well. I had some issues with classes being mixed in my actual dataset, but the tidyverse approach doesn't seem to have any issues dealing with the mismatch.

Answer (score 4):

A base R way would be to identify names of the column which we want to match (here `rep`), then `unlist` them and `match` with `ID` and replace them with corresponding `value`.

```
cols <- grep("^rep", names(df))
df[cols] <- df$value[match(unlist(df[cols]), df$ID)]

df
#   ID rep1 rep2 rep3 rep4 value
#1   a   NA   NA   NA   NA  -400
#2   b -400   NA   NA   NA  -300
#3   c -400 -300   NA   NA  -200
#4   d -400 -300 -200   NA  -300
#5   e -400 -300 -200 -300  -400
#6   f   NA   NA   NA   NA  -400
#7   g -400   NA   NA   NA  -400
#8   h   NA   NA   NA   NA  -400
#9   i   NA   NA   NA   NA  -200
#10  j -200 -300   NA   NA  -300
#11  k -300   NA   NA   NA  -200
#12  l   NA   NA   NA   NA  -300
#13  m   NA   NA   NA   NA  -300
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", 
"i", "j", "k", "l", "m"), rep1 = c(NA, "a", "a", "a", "a", NA, 
"f", NA, NA, "k", "l", NA, NA), rep2 = c(NA, NA, "b", "b", "b", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, "l", NA, NA, NA), rep3 = c(NA, NA, NA, "c", "c", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), rep4 = c(NA, NA, NA, "MA", "d", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), value = c(-400L, -300L, -200L, 
-300L, -400L, -400L, -400L, -400L, -200L, -300L, -200L, -300L, 
-300L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -13L))
```

Comment: This worked using the sample I provided, but I couldn't get it to function properly on my actual data set. It returned everything as NA. `grep` identified the columns to change, `unlist` seemed to work, but `match` didn't. I think the issue is that in the actual data set, value is an integer while the rep columns are factors. This doesn't seem to be an issue with the tidyverse solution however.

Comment: @Corey strange, I think this should still work with factors as well. Can you convert the columns to characters and then check again? `df[cols] <- lapply(df[cols], as.character)`