# Sample using start and end values within a loop in R

Tags: r, loops, sample, seq, mapply

I am trying to sample between a range of values as part of a larger loop in R. As the loop progresses to each row `j`, I want to sample a number between the value given in the `start` column and the value given in the `end` column, placing that value in the `sampled` column for that row.

The results should look something like this:

```
ID  start  end  sampled
a   25     67   44
b   36     97   67
c   23     85   77
d   15     67   52
e   21     52   41
f   43     72   66
g   39     55   49
h   27     62   35
i   11     99   17
j   21     89   66
k   28     65   48
l   44     58   48
m   16     77   22
n   25     88   65
```

I started using `mapply`, which samples the whole df, but then I'm trying to fit all 15 sampled values into a single row.

`df[j,4] <- mapply(function(x, y) sample(seq(x, y), 1), df$start, df$end)`

I thought maybe something using `seq` might work, but this results in errors saying that `from` must be of length 1.

`df[j,4] <- sample(seq(df$start, df$end),1,replace=TRUE)`

The outer looping structure is pretty complicated so I haven't included it here, but the `df[j,4]` part of the code is necessary because it is part of a larger loop. There are situations where rows have to be resampled based on additional dependencies in the actual dataset. For example, the sampled value of `a` might need to be larger than `b`. The rest of the code updates the sampled column, checks for dependencies, and will rerun the sample if the dependencies aren't met. If I can get this sampling section to work, I should be able to plug it in without too much trouble (I hope).

Here's a sample data set.

````
structure(list(ID = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", 
"i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n"), start = c(25, 36, 23, 15, 21, 
43, 39, 27, 11, 21, 28, 44, 16, 25), end = c(67, 97, 85, 67, 
52, 72, 55, 62, 99, 89, 65, 58, 77, 88), sampled = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -14L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(ID = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), start = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), end = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), sampled = structure(list(), class = c("collector_logical", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. 
`df[j,4] <- mapply(function(x, y) sample(seq(x, y), 1), df[j,"start"], df[j,"end"])`

I just needed to be specific as to which row of the sampled values I wanted to enter into `df[j,4]`. Specifying row `j` for columns `start` and `end` did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

First, put the data in a format that is easier to use with `dput(df)`:

```
df <- structure(list(ID = structure(1:14, .Label = c("a", "b", "c", 
    "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n"), class = "factor"), 
    start = c(25L, 36L, 23L, 15L, 21L, 43L, 39L, 27L, 11L, 21L, 
    28L, 44L, 16L, 25L), end = c(67L, 97L, 85L, 67L, 52L, 72L, 
    55L, 62L, 99L, 89L, 65L, 58L, 77L, 88L), sampled = c(44L, 
    67L, 77L, 52L, 41L, 66L, 49L, 35L, 17L, 66L, 48L, 48L, 22L, 
    65L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -14L))
```

You were very close with `mapply()` but you made it harder than it needs to be:

```
df$sampled <- mapply(function(x, y) sample(seq(x, y), 1), df$start, df$end)
df
#    ID start end sampled
# 1   a    25  67      67
# 2   b    36  97      86
# 3   c    23  85      54
# 4   d    15  67      36
# 5   e    21  52      37
# 6   f    43  72      60
# 7   g    39  55      44
# 8   h    27  62      37
# 9   i    11  99      86
# 10  j    21  89      52
# 11  k    28  65      65
# 12  l    44  58      51
# 13  m    16  77      62
# 14  n    25  88      31
```

Comment: `mapply()` works to provide samples for the df, but the `df[j,4]` is necessary because it is part of a larger loop. There are situations where rows have to be resampled. There are additional dependencies in the actual dataset, for instance, the sampled value of `a` might need to be larger than `b`. The rest of the code updates the `sampled` column, checks for dependencies, and will rerun the sample if the dependencies aren't met.

Answer (score 0):

You might not need to loop through. If you want need is something between start and end, it's almost equivalent to sampling something between 0-1 and multiplying that by the range.

```
df %>% mutate(sampled = start + round((end-start)*runif(nrow(.))))
```

Regarding the updating, dependencies you mentioned in your comment: sounds a bit complicated. 
Quick thought: Might be faster to sample a lot of times and choose one that fits your criteria.

Comment: It unfortunately is a bit complicated. The dependency issues are
 here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57000883/if-data-present-replace-with-data-from-another-column-based-on-row-id & here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58335382/if-values-in-a-range-of-columns-arent-present-in-another-column-replace-with-n . Originally my thought was to sample the whole set & basically "re-roll" if dependencies don't match. The problem is that the data set has 1000+ rows and even a test set of 100 entries can take a long time if you're "unlucky". So unfortunately, going row by row is necessary :\