# Ignore NA values in a sample function in R

Tags: r, loops, na, sample, mapply

I am trying to ignore NA values in a sampling function. This relates to an issue earlier regarding sampling using start and end values within a loop in R:
[Sample using start and end values within a loop in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58653809/sample-using-start-and-end-values-within-a-loop-in-r).

I found a solution to the issue using `mapply` : `df[j,4] <- mapply(function(x, y) sample(seq(x, y), 1), df[j,"start"], df[j,"end"])`. I've returned to this issue, but I am having some difficulties in dealing with `NA` values. Normally I would just try to filter out rows with `NA` values in the `start` and `end` columns, but other portions of the loop refer to the rows that would be removed. I've checked other threads discussing using `na.omit` or `na.rm` as possible solutions, but as I said, filtering out rows with `NA` values causes other issues in my code and I don't think that `sample` has a `na.rm` argument, so I'm trying to see if there is another workaround.

I've used the same data set as my previous question but with a few `NA` values added in.
I'd like to end up with something like this below:

```
ID  start  end  sampled
a   25     67   44
b   36     97   67
c   23     85   77
d   15     67   52
e   21     52   41
f   NA     NA   NA
g   39     55   49
h   27     62   35
i   11     99   17
j   21     89   66
k   NA     NA   NA
l   44     58   48
m   16     77   22
n   25     88   65
```

Here's a sample set to use:

```
structure(list(ID = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", 
"i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n"), start = c(25, 36, 23, 15, 21, 
NA, 39, 27, 11, 21, NA, 44, 16, 25), end = c(67, 97, 85, 67, 
52, NA, 55, 62, 99, 89, NA, 58, 77, 88), sampled = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -14L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(ID = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), start = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), end = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), sampled = structure(list(), class = c("collector_logical", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way would be to check for `NA` values in `mapply` :

```
df$sampled <- mapply(function(x, y) if(is.na(x) || is.na(y)) NA else 
                                    sample(seq(x, y), 1), df$start, df$end)
```

Or since this is a part of larger loop using `j` to index rows :

```
df[j,4] <- mapply(function(x, y) if(is.na(x) || is.na(y)) NA else 
                  sample(seq(x, y), 1), df[j,"start"], df[j,"end"])
```

Comment: I've recently had to update R and tidyverse and this solution is resulting in an error "Error: Assigned data `mapply(...)` must be compatible with existing data.
i Error occurred for column `sampled`.
x Can't convert from <integer> to <logical> due to loss of precision.
* Locations: 1.". The new question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62147310/mapply-error-after-updating-r-and-tidyverse. I'd greatly appreciate any thoughts or suggestions you might have. Thanks!